# Python Sorting fetch datetime from filename and sort list

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I do have a list of filenames as given below -

```
ListOfFiles20111012_123717_GwUcRlmXrfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_123742_GwRlmXrfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_123807_PjTmt-Cd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_123808_PjTmt-wCd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_125217_GwRqdolmXrfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_125307_PjTmt-wCd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_130716_GwRqdofCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_130808_PjTmt-5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_132218_GwRqdoJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_132308_PjTmt-Cd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_133904_PjTmt-QwCd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt
ListOfFiles20111012_135218_GwRqdorfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt
```

Objective :

1. Get the list of files.
2. Fetch datetime stamp from the filename e.g. 20111012_135218 [YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS]
3. Sort the list of filenames by datetime stamp.

Any shortcut pythonic way of doing this would be helpful..

I am beginner..

Comment: Is the `ListOfFiles` prefix a constant (same for all the files)? Then just sort the list of files; the datetime format used sorts lexographically in date-time order.

Comment: If the format of the text is fixed to what you have on your question the best way would be to do what @MartijnPieters recommends.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `datetime` and `re` because it gives you all the flexibility of timestamps and regular expressions. If the format of your strings suddenly changes, you cannot simply rely on indexes, therefore I recommend using more flexible methods. However, they are less performant than falsetru's suggestion.

I use a regex to extract the timestamp (you will find the extracted timestamp in `m.groups()[0]`), then parse an actual datetime object out of it, given the format of `timeformat` and pass this as key to the built-in `sorted` function.

To understand the format of the `timeformat` string, refer to the [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation.

```
import datetime
import re

timeformat = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" # this is how your timestamp looks like
regex = re.compile("^ListOfFiles(\d*_\d*)")

def gettimestamp(thestring):
    m = regex.search(thestring)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(m.groups()[0], timeformat)


list_of_filenames = [
    'ListOfFiles20111012_123717_GwUcRlmXrfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_123742_GwRlmXrfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_123807_PjTmt-Cd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_123808_PjTmt-wCd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_125217_GwRqdolmXrfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_125307_PjTmt-wCd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_130716_GwRqdofCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_130808_PjTmt-5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_132218_GwRqdoJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_132308_PjTmt-Cd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_133904_PjTmt-QwCd5f6ZHYO80gA608F9YCJWyM1S1KmF1rG6CvsrtFg8rCs.txt',
    'ListOfFiles20111012_135218_GwRqdorfCPhDSJBXE2TNEQ7h0TC7iJSnHvLxUlCQIdERLcpzw.txt',
]


for fn in sorted(list_of_filenames, key=gettimestamp):
    print fn
```

Comment: Please note that I had forgotten the `return` in the `gettimestamp` method. Huge blunder from my side, sorry. Please use this updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `sorted` function, where you pass the list and a key for sorting. The key here would be
the date parsed from your string format and converted to unix timestamp.